# How to make a bar plot for the following data?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have this data that describes the occurrence of some cell types, in responding patients vs non responsive patients for some drug:

```
> dput(cellsdata)

structure(list(response = c(1, 7, 2, 3, 4, 2, 1, 2, 1, 5, 5, 
4, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 0, 4, 3, 2, 3, 1, 1, 5, 0, 
2, 2, 5, 4, 4, 2), no_response = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 2, 3, 2, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 4, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("Adipocytes", 
"B-cells", "Basophils", "CD4+ memory T-cells", "CD4+ naive T-cells", 
"CD4+ T-cells", "CD4+ Tcm", "CD4+ Tem", "CD8+ naive T-cells", 
"CD8+ T-cells", "CD8+ Tcm", "Class-switched memory B-cells", 
"DC", "Endothelial cells", "Eosinophils", "Epithelial cells", 
"Fibroblasts", "Hepatocytes", "ly Endothelial cells", "Macrophages", 
"Macrophages M1", "Macrophages M2", "Mast cells", "Melanocytes", 
"Memory B-cells", "Monocytes", "mv Endothelial cells", "naive B-cells", 
"Neutrophils", "NK cells", "pDC", "Pericytes", "Plasma cells", 
"pro B-cells", "Tgd cells", "Th1 cells", "Th2 cells", "Tregs"
))
```

I want a bar plot, to look something like this, and I also need it to be in order, from the highest bin on the left to the right.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I guess something like this. First convert the row names to a column. Then turn them into a factor whose levels are ordered according to the sum of your `response` / `no_response` columns. Pivot to long format and use the new `Response` column as the fill variable. The rest is just styling.

```r
library(tidyverse)

cellsdata %>%
  rownames_to_column("Cell") %>%
  mutate(n = response + no_response) %>%
  arrange(-n) %>%
  mutate(Cell = factor(Cell, Cell)) %>%
  select(-n) %>%
  pivot_longer(-Cell, names_to = "Response") %>%
  ggplot(aes(Cell, value, fill = Response)) +
  geom_col(position = "stack") +
  theme_light(base_size = 16) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust = 0.5)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("orange", "#3A43D8"),
                    labels = c("No response", "Response"), name = NULL)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using `reshape2` with your data

```
df$row.names<-rownames(df)
long.df<-reshape2::melt(df,id=c("row.names"))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(long.df, aes(
  fill = variable,
  y = value,
  x = reorder(row.names, -value)
)) +
  geom_bar(position = "stack", stat = "identity") + labs(x = "row name") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(
    angle = 90,
    vjust = 0.5,
    hjust = 1
  ))
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: `reshape2::melt` has long since been superseded by `tidyr::pivot_longer`, [according to the author of both packages](https://github.com/hadley/reshape#status)

Comment: @AllanCameron learn something new everyday, thanks for the info!